# Problem while trying to install rosaria on groovy on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros, installation, ros-groovy, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm following the tutorial on how to use rosaria, available on the link:
http://_www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on my machine. I installed Groovy successfully using the tutorial available on: http://_www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu

When I run the command 'rosmake ROSARIA', nothing seems to be built.
Instead, it seems to be finding a ROS_NOBUILD file and ignoring instead of building the package. I neither created the file nor can I find it anywhere in ROSARIA directory.

When I run the command 'rosrun ROSARIA RosAria' it doesn't find the executable named RosAria, confirming that it isn't being built.

Relevant terminal output available on: http://_pastebin.com/0aN7AETa

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58465/problem-while-trying-to-install-rosaria-on-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.10/) by [mullah_nasruddin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4456/mullah_nasruddin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-03-18**:
Does `rospack find` command show the path to ROSARIA? Also check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable.

**Comment by [mullah_nasruddin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4456/mullah_nasruddin/) on 2013-03-19**:
'rospack find ROSARIA' returns $HOME/ros/amor-ros-pkg/ROSARIA as expected.

echoing 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH' variable returns:
$HOME/ros/amor-ros-pkg:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

Where $HOME is the path to my home directory.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-03-19**:
have you tried catkin_make? As far as I know you have to set a workspace before. Did you set a workspace?

**Comment by [mullah_nasruddin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4456/mullah_nasruddin/) on 2013-03-19**:
I set up a workspace using 'rosws' as explained in the tutorial for rosaria installation. I didn't try catkin_make yet, I'll look onto it and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not yet sure why rosmake doesn't work, but you can manually compile it like this:

```
cd amor-ros-pkg/ROSARIA
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Or use this makefile: https://reedatadept-rosaria.googlecode.com/hg/ROSARIA/Makefile  and then run "make" in the amor-ros-pkg directory.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mullah_nasruddin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4456/mullah_nasruddin/) on 2013-03-20**:
I could successfully run make now, but It can't find aria.h .
If I'm understanding right, I'm currently missing a dependency, libaria.
When I run 'rosdep check ROSARIA' , I'm getting:
'ERROR[ROSARIA]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libaria]'
I don't know how to correctly install it though.

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2013-03-20**:
This worked for me. I had to copy the compiled library from ROSARIA/build/devel/lib/ROSARIA/RosAria to ROSARIA/RosAria before I could rosrun it, though.

**Comment by [Guru666](https://answers.ros.org/users/4545/guru666/) on 2013-03-27**:
after I use the make command it seems to just stop part way through[ 16%] Built target ROSARIA_gencpp
[ 33%] Built target ROSARIA_genlisp
[ 66%] Built target ROSARIA_genpy
[ 83%] Built target ROSARIA_gencfg
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/RosAria.cpp.o
/home/****/ros/amor-ros-pkg/R

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2013-03-27**:
I am also unable to build... I get the error that mullah_nasruddin got above...  "can't fine aria.h".
The tutorial, "ROSARIA's rosmake configuration will download a recent version of the source code for the ARIA library from MobileRobots.com and compile it as well, but I guess that isn't happening?